# Command runs in terminal, but doesn't work in script

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint

On Linux Mint, the command "timedatectl" works as expected from terminal, but doesn't work from the bash script. I think I made some very stupid mistake, as I'm a complete newbie in scripting, but can't find it myself.

```
#!/bin/bash
timedatectl set-timezone UTC
timedatectl status
```

prints out

```
Failed to set time zone: Invalid time zone 'UTC'
Unknown operation status
```

The same commands work just fine from terminal, and setting the timezone and printing out times and time settings.

UPD:

```
which timedatectl
```

prints out

```
/usr/bin/timedatectl
```

, but adding this full path to the calls in the script doesn't change the output.
Trying to set another timezone succeeds from the terminal (timezone changes), but fails from the script. (`Failed to set time zone: Invalid time zone 'Europe/Paris'`)

`echo $PATH` returns

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

The system doesn't ask for password to execute these commands from the terminal.

UPD2: I've found what was wrong, thanks to the comment by Whydoubt. 
I was calling the script like

`bash script1.sh`

but after the comment I tried to call it like

`./script1.sh`

and got

`bash: ./script1.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

So I realised the problem was with the newline symbol (the original script was created on a Windows machine with Notepad++). After retyping the script with xed, everything started to work as expected.

The output of `uname -a`, `hostname`, `hostid` and `hostnamectl`, `who`, `groups`, `stat /usr/share/zoneinfo` and `stat /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC` are the same from the console and from a script. `/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC` is accessible from the script. I think I don't need to show the output as it's rather lengthy and my mistake is already found.

Should I write an answer myself to make the question answered and completed?

Comment: May be bash is not aware of your command. Try doing `which timedatectl` and then put complete path of timedatectl command in your script itself and let us know then.

Comment: Check if the PATH variable is properly set on the server, also try changing to other timezones

Comment: When executing the command in the terminal, do you get asked for a password? If so, how do you have to enter the password? Is there a graphical dialogue?

Comment: Seems like some issue with the linux-mint distribution, can you try on a regular linux server.

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`, `hostname`, `hostid` and `hostnamectl`, `who`, `groups`, `stat /usr/share/zoneinfo` and `stat /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC` from both the console and the script? Does they differ? Can you access `/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC` from your script? Like try if `cat /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC > /dev/null` works? I can replicate the issue with `mv  /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /tmp`. Can you run `strace timedatectl set-timezone UTC` from your script and show the output?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was carriable returns in the script file.

Comment: Yeah - This is off-topic due to a simple typographical error.

Comment: May I ask if I should delete the question, write an answer or do something else?